# Facebook Share a page with a redirect?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, redirect, share

Our site is a members only store, in order to view a product- you need to be a member of the site and logged in.

If a user attempted to go direct to a product without first logging in or registering, the site will redirect them to the landing page where they will need to login / register.

This works great.

Except - if a user wants to share a product on Facebook, we'd like the products details to be shared not the landing page's.

Is it possible for a page with a redirect to be shared on Facebook?

Many thanks :)

Comment: You will have to add an exception from the redirect for the Facebook scraper, so that it can read the Open Graph meta data from the actual URL. You can do that based on the User-Agent header it sends, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#scraperinfo Although be aware, that anyone who “faked” that User-Agent could then also read the content of those pages.

Comment: But IMHO sharing something that is not publicly available on Facebook doesn’t make the most sense in the first place. A lot of people who follow such links from their friend’s postings they see in their newsfeed might just be annoyed that they don’t get to see any actual content, but instead are asked to login to a site they don’t even know.

Comment: @CBroe thank you for the response, agree it could possibly annoy some visitors - its a temporary measure for a site which is on a stage 1 release, in future we won't redirect.

Comment: @CBroe do you know how I would implement this on a wordpress site?

Comment: @CBroe would really appreciate a pointer in the right direction if you have a second? :)

Comment: Not that familiar with WP. If they don’t offer any configuration of the login enforcement that could be used to implement this, then you might need to look for an additional plugin or something. Or another way could maybe be to create a dummy user “for Facebook”, and somehow get that user automatically logged in when the user agent in question is send with the request.